# Datatrigger for Rectangle inside of ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've seen many question on stackoverflow regarding the binding of a `ControlTemplate.Trigger` but I haven't run across any information regarding binding to a `datatrigger` of a control inside of a `ControlTemplate`.

Inside my `ControlTemplate` I have a `Rectangle`.  The fill is normally red except when the `depency property` `Input1Active` is equal to 1.  I have tried the following code but it does not seem to work correctly.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomAxis_IO}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomAxis_IO}">
                <Grid                       
                  <Rectangle Fill="Red">
                    <Rectangle.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=Input1Active}" Value="1">
                                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Rectangle.Style>
                   </Rectangle>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

How can I bind the datatrigger for the rectangle to the dependency property `Input1Active` for the control?

Answer (score 1):

It may be because you're attempting a templatebinding within a style.

As you're inside a ControlTemplate, there's no need to use individual styles for triggers to change the things inside your template anyway.

Try this:

```
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomAxis_IO}">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="InternalRectangle" Fill="Red"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Input1Active" Value="1">
                        <Setter TargetName="InternalRectangle" Property="Fill" Value="Green"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

Using `ControlTemplate.Triggers` and naming parts of the template to set up what your template does is much easier and far more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved my problem.  It looks like I needed to create a `ControlTemplate.Trigger` after all and reference my `Rectangle` I was trying to modify by name.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomAxis_IO}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomAxis_IO}">
                <Grid>


                        <Rectangle Fill="Red" x:Name="Axis1Rect" Width="100" Height="20">

                        </Rectangle>

                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=Input1Active}" Value="1">
                        <Setter TargetName="Axis1Rect" Property="Fill" Value="Green"/>
                    </DataTrigger>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>

        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```